# Multiple select PHP display array value

Tags: php, arrays, post

How to display value name which I selected and hide unselected values in this code?

I mean: now I see "1,0,0,0,0," and I want to see only "red,"

Code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['form_name'])) {

$cols   = array('red', 'green', 'white', 'blue', 'orange');
$query  = "INSERT INTO `m_b_browsing_live` (interests) " . "VALUES (";

$country = '';
foreach ($cols as $col) {
    if (in_array($col, $_POST['service'])) {
        $flag = 1;
    }
    else $flag = 0;

    $query .= "$flag, ";
}

$query .= ')';

// Debug
echo $query;
}
?>

<!-- hold "CTRL" and select something to select multiple -->

<form method="post" action="">
  <select name="service[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="form_name"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You should look into [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Saving multiple values in a comma separated string is a very bad design.

Comment: I think is better to use "something,something,something" in 1 table if you want to save space in your database. If I will create a table with every interests, then I will have about 1000 tables and in every "0" or "1" value.

Comment: Saving space is not the issue here at all. As @MagnusEriksson pointed out you need to normalize that database before going any further. What you are doing will create no end of issues for you going forward.

Comment: _"If I will create a table with every interests"_ - That's not what database normalization is. You create one table with the interests and one "many-to-many" table connecting an item id to an interest id. You should read the link. Right now, with a lot of data, your queries will be slow (the db can't index that column efficiently), harder to search for a specific interest (searching for just `1` will match `10`, `11` and so on) and it will be much harder to remove/edit a specific interest (you need to fetch the complete record and fix it using code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['form_name'])) {

$selected_items = array();

$cols   = array('red', 'green', 'white', 'blue', 'orange');

foreach ( $_POST['service'] as $value => $name ) :
  if ( in_array($name, $cols) ) :
    $selected_items[] = $name;
  endif;
endforeach;

$query  = "INSERT INTO m_b_browsing_live (interests) VALUES ('".implode(',', $selected_items)."')";

echo $query;

}
?>

<!-- hold "CTRL" and select something to select multiple -->

<form method="post" action="">
  <select name="service[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="form_name"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you